# Attempt to find total unique occurrences column as well as return the max value in that column

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am attempting to find the number of occurrences of the "message to user" event per user session as well as return the maximum number of sessions per user. So this means that i would like to keep track of how many user sessions have the event "message to user" but would like to eliminate duplicates that occur in the same session if that makes sense?

I am also looking for the total user sessions across all users

I was unsuccessful trying to find these values. My table looks like so:

```
user_id | event                      | user_session_id

1       | message to user            | 1
1       | message to user            | 1
1       | message from user          | 1
1       | message to user            | 1
1       | message from user          | 2 
1       | message to user            | 2  
1       | message to user            | 3
2       | message to user            | 1
2       | message to user            | 1
2       | message from user          | 1
2       | message to user            | 1
2       | message from user          | 2 
2       | message to user            | 2
```

My expected output would be something like this:

```
user_id | event                      | user_session_id | max_session_by_user | total_sessions 
1       | message to user            | 1               | 3                   | 5
1       | message to user            | 2               | 3                   | 5
1       | message to user            | 3               | 3                   | 5
2       | message to user            | 1               | 2                   | 5
2       | message to user            | 2               | 2                   | 5
```

Thank you

EDIT: I added more clarification about what i meant when i am looking for with regards to the event column

Comment: Can you show us your unsuccessful attempts, please?

Comment: Where does your expected output have the "*number of unique occurrences*"? Also it seems useless to select the `event` column if that's the one you are filtering for.

Comment: You should start small. You want many things, write a query for each individual thing (they seem easy on their own). Some may even need to be broken up in a couple of queries themselves. Afterwards, you can worry about integrating those queries. If you have trouble with that, that might be worth a new question.

Comment: @Bergi 
So the first ting i did was attempt to find each occurrence of 'message to user' per session by using distinct. But where i fell short was when i was unable to return the maximum session id for that user as part of the query. 
```
  SELECT
    DISTINCT
    "user",
    event,
    user_session_id
  FROM sessions
    where event='message to user' and user_id='1';
```
Additionally "number of unique occurrences" was the wrong way to put it. I meant 1 occurrence of that specific event "message to user" per session is what i am looking for

Comment: I will edit my question to be more specific in what i am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter for the desired event and eliminate duplicates.

Then add counts using window functions.

```
SELECT user_id, event, user_session_id,
       count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS max_session_by_user,
       count(*) OVER () AS total_sessions
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, event, user_session_id
      FROM events_table
      WHERE event = 'message to user') AS q;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the `event` column comes from.  But you seem to want:

```
select user, user_session_id,
       count(*) over (partition by user) as max_sessions
from t
group by user, user_session_id;
```

Comment: So my initial question was unclear. How event comes into play is that i wanted to return a row each time the "message to user" event happens but i only want to return one row per session (so ignore the other times it exists in each session for each user).

Comment: @sagnew . . . That explanation is not consistent with your question.  I would suggest that you ask a new question with a clear explanation and correct sample data.